# Django middleware and getting the view name?

Tags: django

I'm trying to write my first middleware in Django.

```
class RefreshBalance:

    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        pass
```

I want to detect if a view is called and refresh a balance. I can see the 'view' argument but don't know how to I use it? For example:

```
if view == "login.dashboard:
   pass
```

How can I find out what view is being called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [middleware documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/#process-view):

> process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args,
>   view_kwargs) request is an HttpRequest object. view_func is the Python
>   function that Django is about to use. (It’s the actual function
>   object, not the name of the function as a string.)

So you need to do something like:

```
from login import dashboard


if view_func.__name__ == dashboard.__name__:
    pass
```

Comment: One way is to compare the name. You can't compare two functions like this (`view_func == dashboard`) in python. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33883671/how-to-test-if-two-functions-are-the-same

Comment: Just `view_func is dashboard` should be enough.

Answer (score -1):

To answer the question:

> I can see the 'view' argument but don't know how to I use it?

Then you are not using the power and beauty of python.

try this this:

```
breakpoint()
if view == "login.dashboard:
   pass
```

This will pause execution, and allow you to interact with python, at that point in code.

Once it pauses execution, the first I do is type `list<ENTER>` to list the code around where it stopped, just to orientate oneself.

Wish to see what type of object `view` is? Type `type(view)`, and now you know!

Want to know what methods and attributes it has, `dir(view)`, and now you know. Or `pp dir(view)` to pretty print it.

Oh it has a `foo_very_interesting_method`, try:

```
solong = view.foo_very_interesting_method
help(solong)
```

If you lucky it will print some helpful info.

Want to see the value of view.bar_attribute, type `view.bar_attrbiute`, and its printed for you.

When done playing type `c` to continue, `q` to quit, `n` to goto the next line, or `s` to step.

And theres a whole lot more if you research `python debugger`.

Enjoy being able to figure out what is going on!