# Using unit-testing for a procedure in Racket

Tags: unit-testing, lisp, racket, dr.racket

If I call in Racket/Dr. Racket the following code:

```
> add1
```

I get:

```
#<procedure:add1>
```

If I am using a library for unit-test called rackunit and I try this:

```
(require rackunit)

(check-equal? add1 #<procedure:add1>)
```

The test fails with a syntax error:

```
read: bad syntax `#<'
```

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For many types of data, [what you `write` can be `read` back](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/read-write.html). But in the case of procedures you can't, and thus it gets outputted as an [unreadable value](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/printing.html#%28part._print-unreadable%29).

Procedure equality is like opaque structure equality: it only checks identity. If this all you need, you will still be able to store the procedure somewhere and use check-equal? (for example, a list with add1 will compare equal to a list with add1). If you need to actually check that the procedure is logically the same, [this is not possible in general](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33883671/how-to-test-if-two-functions-are-the-same/33883834#33883834).