# checking and comparing two Racket contracts?

Tags: racket

Is there a way to compare them? This doesn't work for instance:

```
(equal? (flat-contract integer?) (flat-contract integer?))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to test if two functions are the same?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33883671/how-to-test-if-two-functions-are-the-same)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. First of all, note that the function `flat-contract` is for backward-compatibility, so you probably should not use it. From the documentation:

   > This function is a holdover from before predicates could be used
   >   directly as flat contracts. It exists today for backwards
   >   compatibility.
2. So your question is really to ask if two predicates are the same or not. In general this problem is undecidable due to the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem). However, for your purpose, you might be able to get away with referential equality.

   ```
   > ;; both are in the same memory address
     (eq? integer? integer?) 
   #t
   > ;; obviously not in the same memory address
     (eq? integer? real?)
   #f
   ```

   Please note its caveat

   ```
   > ;; although they look the same syntactically, 
     ;; the function objects are in different memory address
     (eq? (lambda (x) x) (lambda (x) x))
   #f
   > (define x (lambda (x) x))
   > (define y x)
   > ;; both are in the same memory address
     (eq? x y)
   #t
   > ;; flat-contract creates a function in a new memory address
     (eq? (flat-contract integer?) (flat-contract integer?))
   #f
   ```

Comment: See the answer below by Alex Knauth too. It appears that `contract-equivalent?` is less conservative than `eq?`.

Answer (score 6):

For certain kinds of contracts, you can use [`contract-equivalent?`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Building_New_Contract_Combinators.html#(def._((lib._racket%2Fcontract%2Fprivate%2Fguts..rkt)._contract-equivalent~3f))):

```
> (contract-equivalent? (flat-contract integer?) (flat-contract integer?))
#true
> (contract-equivalent? (and/c integer? positive?) (and/c integer? positive?))
#true
> (contract-equivalent? (or/c integer? string?) (or/c string? integer?))
#true
```

This returns `#true` when the contract system can prove that they are equivalent.

However, as the documentation notes, a `#false` result doesn't mean that they're *not* equivalent, it just means it doesn't know:

> This function is conservative, so it may return `#false` when `c1` does, in fact, accept the same set of values that `c2` does.

```
> (contract-equivalent? integer? integer?)
#true
> (contract-equivalent? (lambda (x) (integer? x))
                        (lambda (x) (integer? x)))
#false
```