# Can contracts be matched?

Tags: racket

I'm wondering if contracts can be `match`ed? For instance:

```
(match (listof boolean?)
  [?? (print "hello")])
```

What should I put in `??`? I tried `(struct flat-contract _)` and `(== (listof t))` but neither worked.

Comment: This question might be relevant: [_Comparing two Racket contracts?_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53999357/checking-and-comparing-two-racket-contracts) In particular, you can use [`contract-equivalent?`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Building_New_Contract_Combinators.html#(def._((lib._racket%2Fcontract%2Fprivate%2Fguts..rkt)._contract-equivalent~3f))) for conservative equivalence, so you should be able to use `(== (listof boolean?) contract-equivalent?)`. However, general pattern-matching for looking inside a contract is not supported like that, only equivalence.

Comment: Fascinating question! but... I can't help wondering if this is an XY problem. Are you just curious, or is there a problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Unfortunately it is a problem that I'm trying to solve. I was hoping that contract calls are just structs that can be matched, but I guess not...