# login_exempt_urls not working in my custom middleware

Tags: python, django

I am trying to write a function in my custom middleware so when the user is not logged in they can still register to the site. However with this code 'register' still redirects me to accounts/login. If you could help.

urls.py:

```
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth.views import (
LoginView, LogoutView, PasswordResetView, PasswordResetDoneView,
PasswordResetConfirmView, PasswordResetCompleteView)
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name="home"),
    path('explore/', views.explore, name='explore'),
    path('login/',LoginView.as_view(template_name='accounts/login.html'), name='login'),
    path('logout/', LogoutView.as_view(template_name='accounts/logout.html'), name='logout'),
    path('register/', views.register, name='register'),
    path('profile/', views.view_profile, name='profile'),
    path('profile/edit/', views.edit_profile, name='profile-edit'),
    path('change-password/', views.change_password, name='change-password'),
    path('reset-password/', PasswordResetView.as_view(), name='reset-password'),
    path('reset-password/done/', PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(), name='password_reset_done'),
    path('reset-password/confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/',
         PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('reset-password/complete/', PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(), name='password_reset_complete'),
]
```

Custom_middleware.py:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.shortcuts import redirect


  EXEMPT_URLS = [settings.LOGIN_URL.lstrip('/')]
  if hasattr(settings, 'LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS'):
  EXEMPT_URLS += [url for url in settings.LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS]


class LoginRequiredMiddleware:

   def __init__(self, get_response):
    self.get_response = get_response

   def __call__(self, request):
    response = self.get_response(request)
    return response

   def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args,   view_kwargs):
    assert hasattr(request, 'user')
    path = request.path_info.lstrip('/')
    print(path)

    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        if path not in EXEMPT_URLS:
            return redirect(settings.LOGIN_URL)
```

settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE = [

'tutorial.middleware.LoginRequiredMiddleware',

]

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/accounts/'

LOGIN_URL = '/accounts/login/'

LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS = (

      r'^register/$',

 )
```

Thanks

Comment: when you write `path not in EXEMPT_URLS` this isn't doing a regex match. Since you're printing `path` you can probably see it's not the same string as `'^register/$'`. You have to check `re.match` or `re.search` (see [here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html)) for each of the entries in `EXEMPT_URLS`

Comment: thanks, I tried to add a path instead of a regular expression, would that be the correct way to go about it? and if so how do I format it?

Comment: using regex is fine, as long as you try to match them using the `re` library as I mentioned above. I don't understand what you mean "add a path".

Comment: sorry I meant 'use' ..ok. Thanks for your help

Comment: thanks for your help I got it to work!

Answer (score 0):

As @dirkgroten mentioned above, you would have to try and match the path with to each of the regular expressions in the `LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS` tuple. However, since Django is already matching the path to a view, you could rather match the view names so you won't have to use regular expressions.

So your `LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS` could instead be a list of view names, e.g. `('register',)`. Then you could check if your [view's name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17025885/3486675) is in `LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS` with `if view_func.__name__ in LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS:`.

Comment: thanks I managed to sort it by adding a few things using re.
Best.

Joseph

Comment: @JShen cool. I'd would still recommend you rather use the view name instead of the route path. It's performance should be faster and if the route patterns of your `LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS` ever change, you won't have to change them in your `settings.py` as well.